# Javascript output instance of a object with loop

Tags: javascript, loops, object, instance

I have several instances of an object:

```
function objectname=(prop1,prop2){
    this.prob1=prob1
    this.prob2=prob2
}

var object1=objectname(
    "11",
    "12");
var object2=objectname(
    "21",
    "22");
```

Now i want to output it. This works:

```
document.write(object1.prob1); //output 11
```

Now i want a loop over all different instances like

```
for (var key in objectname){
    document.write(objectname.key.prob1)}  //Does not work
```

The problem is that an easy example also does not work:

```
document.write(objectname.object1.prob1); //Does not work
```

Why?

Comment: The second one doesn't work because `objectname` doesn't have a property `object1`. `objectname` does not magically have a list of instances. You have to create on if you want one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain mistakes in your code and you need to fix them first to achieve what you want. First you have a mistake in defining your function, there is an extra `=` sign there, these are all the possible ways to define your function:

```
function ObjectName (prop1,prop2){
    this.prob1=prob1
    this.prob2=prob2
}

var ObjectName = function (prop1,prop2){
    this.prob1=prob1
    this.prob2=prob2
};

var ObjectName = function ObjectName (prop1,prop2){
    this.prob1=prob1
    this.prob2=prob2
};
```

The other point is related to `this` keyword. Whenever you use `this` keyword in your function you are able to use your functions in couple of certain ways:

1- Using `new` keyword: It seems based on what you mean by instances, your code is missing a `new` keyword:

```
function ObjectName(prop1,prop2){
    this.prob1=prob1
    this.prob2=prob2
}

var object1=new ObjectName(
    "11",
    "12");
var object2=new ObjectName(
    "21",
    "22");
```

2- Using `call` or `apply`:

```
var object1 = {}
ObjectName.call(object1,
    "11",
    "12");
```

or:

```
var object2 = {}
ObjectName.apply(object2,[
    "21",
    "22"
]);
```

Or if you don't want to use `new` keyword, to have a safe object creation process you better use `Object.create(prototypeObject)` like:

```
var object1 = Object.create(ObjectName.prototype);
ObjectName.call(object1,
    "11",
    "12");
```

This would allow you to define your other methods and variables in `ObjectName.prototype` like:

```
ObjectName.prototype.myVar = "Anything";
```

At the end To loop over all the instance you should first store them somewhere. You could do it like:

```
function ObjectName(prop1,prop2){
    ObjectName.instances.push(this);
    this.prob1=prob1
    this.prob2=prob2
}
ObjectName.instances = [];
```

Then you can loop over `ObjectName.instances` which is an array consisting all of your instances.

```
var instance,
    i = 0, l = ObjectName.instances.length;

for ( ; i < l ; i++ ){
    instance = ObjectName.instances[i];
    //document.write(objectname.key.prob1)}
    console.log(instance.prob1);
}
```

NEVER use `document.write` for your outputs, it has different effects in different situation on your page, depending on when you call it. Create you DOM objects like `div` elements and put your data inside them.

The other point that is worth nothing is the way I have defined your function in camel-case, with a upper first letter. This is kind of convention for creating JavaScript functions that are going to be used as a constructor.

Comment: Thanks so far. I did forget to write down new. 
The loop still does not work.
    for (var key in ObjectName.instances){
        document.write(ObjectName.instances.key[prop1]);}

Comment: @user2867054: check out the loop and think of doing something safe to output your data instead of `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
objectname.key[prob1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you just forgot to add

```
 new
```

keyword. This code

```
objectname(
"11",
"12")
```

has window object as

```
 this
```

so actually when you create object 2 it overrides values from object1.

try

```
new objectname(
"11",
"12")
```

returning to the problem of your loop

```
 objectname
```

is just a function, you won't get expected propertieds from it.
if you want to get all instances try

```
 var instances = []
 instances.push(new objectname("1","2"))
 instances.push(new objectname("3","4"))
 for(var i in instances)
     document.write(instances[i].prob1)
```